# Greek characters in Julia embedded code

Tags: listings, package-writing, extended-characters, julia

I have a problem regarding jlcode package.

The package documentation can be found here:
https://github.com/m3g/jlcode_example/blob/master/jlcode.sty

I have modified the default color theme to match my liking. This includes, a green colour for the comments and a grey-ish colour for the base as shown below:

```
\definecolor{jlbase}{HTML}{444444}%         % julia's base 
\definecolor{jlcomment}{HTML}{00B359}%      % julia's comments
```

The problem is that toned greek characters (e.g. ά, έ) have the "jlbase" colour, even when they are used after the "#" command, which marks a comment, as written in the package. All the other greek characters have the "jlcomment colour" as they should. In addition to that, the toned greek characters are being put to the front of every greek word !?

Here's a picture to visualise the problem :

[image]

The code used is written down below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=160mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Futura}
\usepackage[theme=defult]{jlcode}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{jllisting}[language=julia, style=jlcodeuccstyle]
#MAIN PROCESS
function    #Ακέραιο μέρος
if abs(n)<1
    aker = [0]
else  
    while (flag==0) #το πολύ 23 bits για αποθήκευση   αριθμού(επειδή 1ο ψηφίο κατά την αποθήκευση 
        #το 1, μπορώ να θεωρήσω ότι θα αποθηκεύσω άλλα 23 ψηφία)
        append! VS apend #(aker,mod(AkeraioMeros,b)) 
       global AkeraioMeros = div(AkeraioMeros,b) #πηλίκο διαίρεσης ακεραίου μέρους με b
        if (AkeraioMeros==0)
            flag=1; #break 
        end
    end
    aker=reverse(aker)  #αναποδογυρίζουμε  διάνυσμα με ψηφία ακε̇ραιου μέρους
end 
println('θέλω να σε') 
% 
\end{jllisting}
\end{document}
```

I would like the text to be shown as written in the code above (with the same order of the letters inside every word) and
**ALL** the characters following the "#" command to have a green colour(jlcomment colour)

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: sorry your question is impossible to understand please make an example that shows the issue. you just show a fragment of tex code using undefined commands, what is `\lst@mode` or `\lst@Pmode` ? Also the code shown doesn't appear to be related to Unicode, it just compares to integers and if they are equal sets something in a color.

Comment: It's a part from the jlcode package which at the beginning loads listings and xcolor package and the" jlbase colour" is already defined

Comment: But you need to _say_ that in the question, and provide an example that people can run, but as I said in a comment on your last question the code seems fundamentally mistaken it is using math mode accents to typeset Greek text.  Also you need to give a link to jlcode.sty as it is not in the standard tex distributions

Comment: It doesn't seem quite right to me as well, but I am lost trying to understand what causes the problems I am facing. That's why I approach the problem like that. Thanks a lot for helping me to improve the question!

Comment: rather than posting two lines of code with no context that allows anyone to run it you should provide a top level description of what you actually want to do and provide a complete small document that has the desired input and say what output you expect. As it is I can't see how anyone can help.

Comment: OK finally you linked to the package, I would remove all the parts using mathmode for Greek and just use latex's standard textual Greek setting. But you still have not provided a test document or said what output it should produce.

Comment: If I run that example I get `! LaTeX Error: The font size command \normalsize is not defined:
               there is probably something wrong with the class file.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1 \begin{document}
                    
? `

Comment: Updated the code with the preamble

Comment: oh ! for the first time you indicate you are using xelatex, never use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` with xelatex (it does no harm, just generaes a warning that it should not be used), don't use `\usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}` either they are legacy packages that don't really help. None of the `unicode` support in that jlcode package is designed for xelatex or lualatex

Comment: I removed all the parts using math mode for Greek and the problem with the order of the letters was fixed. However, now all the greek letters have the "jlbase" colour, even when used as comments. I tried using latin characters as comments and they have the "jlcomments" colour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pacakges you are using do not appear to b designed for a Unicode TeX.
I go this ouput with `minted` (and `xlatx --shell-escape)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=160mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
% no \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% no \usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Times New Roman}
% I don't have this \setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Futura}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono} % a tt font that has Greek
% probably not \usepackage[theme=defult]{jlcode}
\usepackage{minted}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\small
\begin{minted}{julia}
#MAIN PROCESS
function    #Ακέραιο μέρος
if abs(n)<1
    aker = [0]
else  
    while (flag==0) #το πολύ 23 bits για αποθήκευση   αριθμού(επειδή 1ο ψηφίο κατά την αποθήκευση 
        #το 1, μπορώ να θεωρήσω ότι θα αποθηκεύσω άλλα 23 ψηφία)
        append! VS apend #(aker,mod(AkeraioMeros,b)) 
       global AkeraioMeros = div(AkeraioMeros,b) #πηλίκο διαίρεσης ακεραίου μέρους με b
        if (AkeraioMeros==0)
            flag=1; #break 
        end
    end
    aker=reverse(aker)  #αναποδογυρίζουμε  διάνυσμα με ψηφία ακε̇ραιου μέρους
end 
println('θέλω να σε') 
% 
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to solve all the problems mentioned above. Thanks a lot!
Your suggestions, also helped me fix all the problems I had without using the `\usepackage{minted}`. However, I would also like to know if there is a way to change what's being selected as "basic style " when using the command `\lstdefinestyle{stylename}{basicstyle=..........}`